# JAVA Как поменять значение int в ответе на double

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! Только начал изучать JAVA, точнее предмет новый в Уни строительная информатика. Так вот получил первую дом. работу.

Суть такова, нужно ввести переменную `int z = 5;` потом `z` делить на два и ответ сохранить как переменную содержащую вещественное число (я предполагаю это `double`), но в ответе все равно стоит `2.0` вместо `2,5`. В задании стоит найти решение этой проблемы и привести ответ в нужный и правильный вид. Я очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь!

```
package anwendung;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Aufgabe_1

        // lokale Variablen
        int a = 5;
        int b = 23; 

        //Berecnung von a+b

        System.out.println("a + b = " +(a + b));

        //Berechnung b%a

        System.out.println("b % a= " + (a % b));

        //Berechnung b/a

        System.out.println("b / a = " + (b/a));

        //Berechnung a++

        System.out.println("a++ = " + (a++));

        //Berechnung b--

        System.out.println("a * b = " + (a*b));

        // Berechnung a+

        System.out.println("a+ = b = " + (a+=b));

        //Berechnung a*b++

        System.out.println("a * b ++ = " + (a*b++));

        //Berechnung a<=b

        System.out.println("a < + b =" + (a<=b));

        //Berechnung a>b

        System.out.println("a > b =" + (a>b));

        //Berechnung

        System.out.println("a == b =" + (a==b));

        //Berechnung a!=b

        System.out.println("a ! = b =" + (a!=b));

        //Aufgabe_2


        //Aufgabe_3

        //Neue Variable 

        int c = 2147483647;

        System.out.println(" c + 1 = " + (c + 1));

        // Variable "c"  ist um 1 erhöht und Wert ist jetzt negativ, 

        /* Wenn durch eine Operation der Wertebereich über- oder unterschritten wird, Programmiersprachen reagieren 
        so dass, dass bei derAddition der Zahl 1 auf die größte positive Zahl des Wertebereichs die kleinste negative 
        Zahl des Wertebereichs alsErgebnis ausrechnen   
        */

        //Aufgabe_4

        int z = 5;

        double p = z / 2;


        System.out.println(p);



    }

}
```

Comment: `double p = z / 2.0;`

Comment: @Schweigert Vitalij  Из вашего вопроса так и не понятно, какой результат вы хотите получить: то ли 2.0, то ли 2.5.

Comment: мне нужно, что бы в ответе стояло 2,5. Но добиться этого я не могу.
,

Comment: Алексей, большое спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли! Хорошего Вам настроения!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении с объявлением переменной `p` типа `double`

```
double p = z / 2;
```

в качестве инициализатора используется целочисленной выражение

```
z / 2
```

так как оба операнда оператора `/` имеют целый тип. Поэтому в результате вы получите, что переменная `z` будет иметь значение `2.0`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы данное выражение вычислялось как выражение чисел с плавающей запятой, то по крайней мере один из операндов должен иметь тип `double`

Например,

```
double p = z / 2.0;
```

или

```
double p = z / 2d;
```

Имейте в виду, что в вашей программе есть опечатки, как, например, следующая

```
System.out.println("b % a= " + (a % b));
                                ^^^^^
```

Должно быть

```
System.out.println("b % a= " + (b % a));
                                ^^^^^
```

Или между некоторыми операторами, которые состоят из двух символов, как, например, этот `!=` , вы вставляете пробел, что может привести к ошибке компиляции.

Comment: Vlad from Moscow большое Вам спасибо! Счастья Вам!

Comment: @SchweigertVitalij Не за что. Пометьте лучший с вашей точки зрения ответ, и ваш вопрос тем самым будет отвечен.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас тут целочисленное деление.

При делении целочисленного `a` на целочисленное `b` результат округляется вниз до целого числа.

Чтобы получить значение с плавающей точкой Вы можете явно преобразовать один из операндов к типу числа с плавающей точкой, например так:

```
double p = (double) z / 2;
```

или так:

```
double p =  z / (double) 2;
```

или вот так:

```
double p =  z / 2.0;
```